# Разложение в сумму кубов

Tags: c++, олимпиада

учу рюкзак, первое задание разложение в сумму кубов, алгоритм правильный, но на 1300 и более ничего не выводит, может переполнение но я все перепробовал, помогите пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n; cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n + 1);
    vector<vector<int>> arr(n + 1, vector<int>(n + 1, 0));
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; ++i) {
        a[i] = i * i * i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n + 1; ++j) {
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j - 1];
            if (i >= a[j]) {
                if (arr[i][j] == 0 || arr[i][j] > arr[i - a[j]][j] + 1) {
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i - a[j]][j] + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << arr[n][n];
}
```

Comment: `может переполнение`  - ну вот, вы же сами все знаете. Выберите подходящий тип (64-разрядный)

Comment: я уже все испробовал, можете указать на ошибку (по идее переполнение не может быть так как у любого числа максимальная сумму кубов это само число, так как мы берем такое же кол во единиц)

Comment: 1300^3 > max int 2^31, используйте long long

Comment: спасибо огромное, просто не поменял тип у переменной цикла из за того и ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вы заметили, граничное значение 1300, куб которого не входит в диапазон `int`:  `1300^3 > max int (2^31)`

Используйте внутри векторов 64-разрядный `long long`,а чтобы произведение не переполнялось при i:int, можно компилятору подcказать:

```
a[i] = (long long)i * i * i;
```

Comment: теперь не работает при 10 ** 6, вообще без понятия почему

Comment: Вы серьёзно? Причина та же, только максимальное long long = 9*10^18. Но как вы собрались делать таблицу в (10^6)^2=10^12 элементов и обрабатывать её?

Comment: Нужно привести точное условие задачи с заданными ограничениями

Comment: а что если разделить таблицу на несколько частей

Comment: а условие такое : Дано натуральное число N. Необходимо представить его в виде суммы точных кубов, содержащей наименьшее число слагаемых. Программа должна вывести это число слагаемых. Программа получает на вход натуральное число N, не превосходящее 10 ** 6.

Comment: Так если N <= 10 ** 6, то и кубы будут не больше, зачем миллион-то в куб возводить, если достаточно 100^3

Comment: Т.е. у вас всего 100 возможных слагаемых.

Comment: зашло, спасибо большое